# C# Webbrowser simulate click

Tags: click, htmlelements, dom-selection

I want simulate click to c# webbrowser. But I could not successful.

This Html Code to be clicked:

```
<a aria-label="2" class="rrl" href="javascript:ok();"><span class="ess ch"></span>2</a>
<a aria-label="3" class="rrl" href="javascript:ok();"><span class="ess ch"></span>3</a>
<a aria-label="4" class="rrl" href="javascript:ok();"><span class="ess ch"></span>4</a>
<a aria-label="5" class="rrl" href="javascript:ok();"><span class="ess ch"></span>5</a>
```

My incorrect C# click code:

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
 {
    if (el.GetAttribute("aria-label") == "4")
    {
       el.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
 }
```

i want to click by area-label number

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
 {
     if (el.OuterHtml.Contains("</span>4</a>"))
     {
         el.InvokeMember("click");
         break;
     }
 }
```